# Jquery ajax error Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, api

im getting some errors with bulding a Rest api client..... im quite new so plz help me
 The error that im getting is: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
<input name="commandurl" type="text" id="URL" size="60" value="">
            <h2>Message Body:</h2>
            <textarea name="messagebody" id="message" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>
            <h2>Command Response:</h2>
            <textarea name="response" id="res" rows="25" cols="100"></textarea>
            <div id="buttons">
                <button type="button" onclick="GET()">GET</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="">PUT</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="">POST</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="">DELETE</button>
            </div>
        </form></center>



<script language="JavaScript">
var URL = document.getElementById("#URL");
var message = document.getElementById("#message");
function GET(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: URL,
    data: message, 
    success: function(data){
    alert("Succes");        
     $("#res").html(data); 
    }
   }
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need the `#` getting the getElementById

Comment: Also, check your closing brackets in `get`. They're a bit iffy.

Answer (score 0):

As Albert says, you don't need the hash when you use [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). So:

```
document.getElementById('message');
```

You would need it if you used [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which is where the mistake might have arisen.

But you also need to get the `value` of the `textarea` otherwise you'll be passing in the HTML element which is why you're getting the error.

```
var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2zxaf6L4/8/)

Also, here's your function with the proper closing brackets.

```
function GET() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: URL,
    data: message,
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Succes");
      $("#res").html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

If you indent your code properly this kind of issue will be easier to identify in future.

Comment: @mvar `message = document.getElementById("#message").value;` I'll update my answer.